# Deriving a mapping

Tags: real-analysis

Given the inputs $(i,j)=(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2)... $ find a function such that $f(i,j)=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...$

I have tried by trial and error for a long time and have yet to come up with an equation that $f(1,1)=1$ and $f(2,1)=2$ and $f(2,2)=3$...

Is there a non trial&error method to come up with this?

It is easy to satisfy two, but I can't get passed that.

Comment: $\frac {i(i-1)}{2}+j$?

Comment: Genius! Thank you! it seems to work up through (4,j)!

Comment: I'll write up an argument for it and post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To think this through note that it is fairly easy to compute $f(i,1)$.  After all, there is one pair of the form $(1,*)$.  Two pairs of the form $(2,*)$ and, generally, $k$ pairs of the form $(k,*)$.  Thus $$f(i,1)=1+2+3+\dots+(i-1)+1=\frac {i(i-1)}{2}+1$$ It follows at once that $$f(i,2)=\frac {i(i-1)}{2}+2$$ and, generally, $$f(i,j)=\frac {i(i-1)}{2}+j$$